# AngularJS - Pass assignment to a directive callback

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that displays an icon with a little cross. When the user clicks on this cross, a callback should be called.

Here's the code of the directive template:

```
<div class="item" title="{{name}}">
  <button type="button" class="close">
    <span ng-click="onDelete()">&times;</span>
  </button>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></span>
</div>
```

The Javascript of the directive:

```
angular.module('hiStack').directive('hsItem', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: 'item.tpl.html',
    scope: {
      onDelete: '&',
      title: '@'
    }
  };
});
```

Finally, the code that uses the directive:

```
<hs-item on-delete="deleteGroupModal = true" title="TestTitle"></hs-item>
```

`deleteGroupModal = true` is never called when I click on the cross. If I pass a function instead like `deleteGroup()`, it works.
How can I pass an assignment like we usually do with `ng-click` for example?

Thank you.

Comment: You have to create and pass function in which you will define: deleteGroupModal = true and it should work. It is not possible without declaring a function. & is used for it.

Comment: Isn't it possible to do like the `ng-click` directive like `ng-click="test = true"` ?

Comment: What do you mean by "like ng-model directive"? In ng-model you can only pass variable ($scope) without any condition.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, I meant like the `ng-click`

Comment: Nope, it is not possible. & in directive expects only function. You can use @ if you need only a value if you need true or false and then create function inside your directive.

Comment: Ok, too bad. I find pass assignment instead function more pretty.

Comment: It's not, trust me. If you create function, you will have centralized everything on one place. If you need some change in future, it will be easy to change.

Answer (score 1):

As Igor Janković said, it's better to pass a function than to write it directly on the attribute.

That said, it's possible to eval the expression passed on the attribute like this:

```
angular.module('hiStack').directive('hsItem', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: 'item.tpl.html',
    scope: {
      title: '@'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.onDelete = function() {
            // Eval the code on the parent scope because directive's scope is isolated in this case
            if (attrs.onDelete) scope.$parent.$eval(attrs.onDelete);
        }
    }
  };
});
```